# Open an external EXE. file using VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Please help me make this code works. I want to open an external EXE file using Powerpoint VBA.

```
Sub open_test()
Dim FileName, FSO, MyFile
FileName = "C:\test.exe"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
End Sub
```

There are no compiler errors, but when i execute the macro, it does nothing ... I have another alternatives to this code? please help me, *thanks*!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the file? The code that you have listed opens C:\test.txt as a `TextStream`, it just does nothing with the stream.

Comment: ohh ... sorry ... i want to execute an external exe. file ... (like shell comand) ... but i don't know how to do it ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to start the program, try using

```
Sub open_test()
    Dim sFullPathToExecutable as String
    sFullPathToExecutable = "C:\test.exe"
    Shell sFullPathToExecutable 
End Sub
```