# How can I check IF a version of Ghostscript is installed and IF SO where it is installed?

Tags: vba, vbscript, registry

As the title says. I need to check in VBS whether (1) Ghostscript is installed on the local computer and if so (2) where it is installed.

I think question (1) I have solved:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:!root/default:StdRegProv")
    If oReg.EnumKey(HKLM, "SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\", arrSubKeys) = 0 Then
    KeyExists = True
Else
    KeyExists = False 'The script stops since it requires GS to be installed
End If

...

objShell.Run(pathToGhostScript & "-arguments")
```

However, in my case GS in the registry looks like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.01\
```

Note: I'm checking for a registry entry `SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\` and not `SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.01\` because my check would return `FALSE` if someone would have installed `...\9.2\` or something. I'm assuming that whichever version might be installed, the registry key `SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\` would always exist. Is this assumption correct?

Eventually, I need to call (in my case) `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32.exe`. If I look at the registry, the path to `..\bin\` can only bderived from the registry value `SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.01\GS_DLL`, which returns `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gsdll32.dll`. I assume I could take this value, remove everything after `..\bin\` and concatenat `gswin32.exe` to the path. I would then have filled the `pathToGhostScript` variable in my script above.

Question: how do I return the value for `GS_DLL` from my script? Because I know the value can be found under `..\9.01\GS_DLL` in my case, but on someone else's pc it might also be eg. `..\9.57\GS_DLL`...

My questions:

1. Is this the best approach?
2. If not, what would be a more robust approach to see if gswin32.exe is available?
3. If so, could you help me fill in the blanks discussed above?

Comment: if the path (*read. folder structure*) is always the same with an exception of the version. Why don't you use a `Dir()` function with simple regex to check whether the `gswin32.exe` exists in `Program Files\.....\.`? Also, why are you checking for the `*.exe` itself why don't you try to instantiate an instance and check whether that was successful or not

Comment: Thanks, but what you are suggesting is too advanced for me at this point to follow-up upon. Could you please elaborate how I could instantiate an instance and see whether it was succesful or not?

Comment: I am sure its not that advanced maybe it just sounds like that I am sure what you're doing now is far more complicated. Here, see [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552638/open-an-external-exe-file-using-vba-powerpoint)

Comment: That would not work, because then I would have to check every possible version of GS: `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32.exe`, `..\gs9.02\bin\gswin32.exe`, `gs9.03\bin\gswin32.exe` etc. I would need to determine first (through the registry I guess) *which* GS version is installed and *where* it is installed, before calling an instance, I guess.

Comment: You wouldn't. Use wildcards or regex

Comment: @mehow Doesn't work that way in VBScript.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry I am a bit lost here... can you be more specific what does not work in VBS?

Comment: @mehow Shelling out (e.g. via the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method) doesn't work with wildcards or regular expressions, i.e. something like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\gs\*\bin\gswin32.exe"""` will fail.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Oh alright, thanks for pointing that out I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's safe to assume that the Ghostscript executable will be located in the same directory as the DLL, so something like this should work:

```
Const HKLM    = &h80000002
Const baseKey = "SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript"
Const value   = "GS_DLL"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

If reg.EnumKey(HKLM, baseKey, subkeys) <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Cannot enumerate subkeys of " & baseKey & "."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

For Each sk In subkeys
  If reg.GetStringValue(HKLM, baseKey & "\" & sk, value, gsLib) <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Cannot read value " & value & "."
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

gsDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(gsLib)
gs = fso.BuildPath(gsDir, "gswin32.exe")

WScript.Echo gs
```

Comment: Actually, there are two Ghostscript keys that has to be checked: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120231/how-to-determine-where-an-executable-is-installed/21120659#21120659