# How to determine where an executable is installed?

Tags: vba, vbscript

On my machine, Ghostscript (GS) is installed at:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32.exe
```

But on another machine, a different version might have been installed:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs7.52\bin\gswin32.exe
```

Or even in a completely different subfolder:

```
C:\Program Files\ghost\script\gs8.00\bin\gswin32.exe
```

I'm trying to find a VBS function to determine the path where `gswin32.exe` can be found on the current machine, first trying with only a different subfolder to `\gs\`:

```
Set oShell = createObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Program Files\gs\*\bin\gswin32.exe")
```

This, however, does not work. Nor does any other wildcard in the path. I'm now doubting whether this is the right approach, so my question is:

**How can I determine where the executable gswin32.exe is installed?**

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is to check the registry.

What you are looking for are this two registry keys:

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AFPL Ghostscript

If Ghostscript is installed on the machine, you should find at least one of above.

Those keys contain installed Ghostscript version sub-keys...which contains string values which points to dll / exe file.

Also, make sure you don't hardcode 'gswin32.exe' file name as on the 64 bit OS the name is 'gswin64.exe'.